# Does XAMPP on Linux install Apache, PHP, etc separately & how do I upgrade it?

Tags: php, apache, xampp

I am looking to install XAMPP on Ubuntu 16.04LTS.

The website says that it includes:

`Apache 2.4.27, MariaDB 10.1.26, PHP 7.1.8 + SQLite 2.8.17/3.7.17 + multibyte (mbstring) support, Perl 5.16.3, ProFTPD 1.3.4c, phpMyAdmin 4.7.2, OpenSSL 1.0.2l, GD 2.0.35, Freetype2 2.4.8, libpng 1.5.26, gdbm 1.8.3, zlib 1.2.8, expat 2.0.1, Sablotron 1.0.3, libxml 2.0.1, Ming 0.4.5, Webalizer 2.23-05, pdf class 0.11.7, ncurses 5.9, pdf class 0.11.7, mod_perl 2.0.8-dev, FreeTDS 0.91, gettext 0.18.1.1, IMAP C-Client 2007e, OpenLDAP (client) 2.4.21, mcrypt 2.5.8, mhash 0.9.9.9, cUrl 7.45.0, libxslt 1.1.29, libapreq 2.12, FPDF 1.7, ICU4C Library 4.8.1, APR 1.5.2, APR-utils 1.5.4`

Will this attempt to use the packages installed on my computer, or will these be installed separately?

Also how do you upgrade it to a newer version?

Comment: Why would you need to install XAMPP?  The `AMP` portion of XAMPP implies Apache, MySQL (or MariaDB), and PHP, so you already have the basic "packages" that XAMPP typically contains, which are the first 3 items that you listed. It looks like that phpMyAdmin is also present, so that would be a bonus.

Comment: I had some issues installing the different packages required. If I use tasksel or something like that I don't easily know what packages that has installed for future reference. With XAMPP I have everything in one place, I know what it contains and I have a handy GUI control panel to turn parts off or on and quickly open up the config files for Apache, etc